# Create smooth line to join N points in 3 dimensions

Tags: c++, graphics, spline

I have N points in 3-dimensional space. I need to join them using a line. However, if I do that using a simple line, it is not smooth and looks ugly.

My current approach is to use a Bezier curve, using the DeCasteljau algorithm for 4 points, and running that for each group of 4 points in my data set. However, the problem with this is that since I run it on say points 1-4, 5-8, 9-12, etc., separately, the line is not smooth between 4-5, 8-9, etc.

I also looked for other approaches; specifically I found [this article](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/) about Catmull-Rom splines, which seem even better suited for my purpose, because the curve passes through all control points, unlike the Bezier curve. So I almost started implementing that, but then, I saw on that site that the formula works `"assuming uniform spacing of control points"`. That is not the case for my problem.

So, my question is, what approach should I use -- Bezier, Catmull-Rom, or something completely different? If Bezier, then how to fix the non-smoothness between 4-5, 8-9, etc.? If Catmull-Rom, why won't the formula work if points are not evenly spaced, and what do I need instead?

**EDIT:** I am now pretty sure I want the Catmull-Rom spline, as it passes every control point which is an advantage for my application. Therefore, the main question I would like answered is why won't the formula on the link I provided work for non-uniformly spaced control points?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of your line?  Do you just want a line that is pleasing on the eye, or something more quantitively meaningful.  For example, you might want the most probable curve through your data points assuming, say, Gaussian noise?

Comment: @Tom: basically I get the points from a physics simulation, the smoothing of the line is just to show the final result, so I guess just pleasing for the eyes :)

Comment: @houbysoft In that case, why are you wanting to write the plotter yourself, why not just output the data and plot in, say, gnuplot.

Comment: @Tom: the end result will be shown in a special 3D room operated by more than 1 computer, which needs a specific application to do the work. Moreover, I'll need to add some interactivity to the plotter, like communicate with head-tracking devices, etc. The point is, the application is quite specific and goes beyond just showing the line, so gnuplot would not work.

Comment: Do you want the line to `PASS` every point and be smooth, or just go through the points without passing everyone, if the second case, google for "multi dimensional regression analysis"

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: just pass every point and be smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of solutions:

- Use a B-spline. This is a generalization of Bezier curves (a Bezier curve **is** a B-spline with no internal knot points.)
- Use a cubic spline. Cubic splines are particularly easy to calculate. A cubic spline is continuous in the zero, first, and second derivatives across the control points. The third derivative, the cubic term, suffers a discontinuity at the control points, but it is very hard to see those discontinuities.

One key difference between a B-spline and a cubic spline is that the cubic spline will pass through all of the control points, while a B-spline does not. One way to think about it: Those internal control points are just suggestions for a B-spline but are mandatory for a cubic spline.

Comment: To add to this answer, cubic splines don't require even control point spacing like the OP stated too.  You just need a good parameterization (arc-length if you can) to ensure even distributions of the interpolated points. Particularly check out Cardinal splines (of which Catmull-Rom is a subclass), they have adjustable curvature (tension) and are a great little cubic spline for graphics.

Comment: @Ron Warholic: ah, so basically the only problem if I use the formula for non-evenly spaced points is that if I always draw say 10 points of the new curve for each pair of data points, sometimes these new points will not be evenly spaced, correct?

Comment: Pretty much.  If you parameterize your interpolation based on the arc-length between control points however you will get pretty much perfectly spaced points--this can be a bit harder to implement though.

Answer (score 0):

A meaningful line (although not the simplest to evaluate) can be found via Gaussian Processes.  You set (or infer) the lengthscale over which you wish the line to vary (i.e. the smoothness of the line) and then the GP line is the most probable line through the data given the lengthscale.  You can add noise to the model if you don't mind the line not passing through the data points.

Its a nice interpolation method because you can also obtain the standard deviation of your line.  The line becomes more uncertain when you don't have much data in the vacinity.

You can read about them in chapter 45 of David MacKay's `Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms` - which you can download from the author's website [here](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html).

Answer (score 0):

one solution is the following page in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve, check the generalized approach for N control points.